# How fill a LABLE with text on two different pages on the menu but where go to same page?

Tags: vb.net

I one page, with 3 labels like this:

```
    LBL_SelectPlant.Text = "TLH"
    LBL_OrderType.Text = "Sample Shop"
    LBL_CreateOrder.Text = "Engineering"
```

In main menu i have two options:

Sample Shop and Tool Shop

My problem is that, when i click in menu Sample Shop my LBL_OrderType fill with Sampmple shop and when i click in menu Tool Shop LBL_OrderType filling with Tool Shop. I know, in my example is string defined by me, but how i do to filling with that value (Sample Shop or Tool Shop) when i press two buttton from main menu?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you using c# or vb.net? please decide and adjust tags.

Comment: Sorry, i just edit my post right now. Just vb.net

Comment: is that main menu that you're refering to is a toolbar or separate window? or if you can post a photo of your windows form, it'll be much better :)

Comment: @Kim jaca i put a picture with two menus, Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "when i press two buttton from main menu"? Do you mean that you're going to select 2 order type?

Comment: When in click to Sample Shop must open UpdateSample.asp but in my label put "Sample Shop" when i click on Tool Shop going to same page, UpdateSample.asp but in label put Tool Shop.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx like that